# How to assign INSERT INTO ... RETURNING value to a variable

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am doing a project in Jupyter Notebook on Python with SQL iPython Magic extension (postrgresql).
I have an inventory table

```
%%sql
   CREATE TABLE inventory (
   inventory_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(20),
   price INT,
   sku VARCHAR(10))
```

and a diamonds table

```
%%sql
   CREATE TABLE diamonds (
   diamond_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   shape VARCHAR(20),
   carats REAL,
   color VARCHAR(20),
   clarity VARCHAR(20),
   cut VARCHAR(20),
   price INT,
   inventory_id INT)
```

I create data in for loop to populate my inventory and diamonds tables.

```
for i in range(10):

shape = random.choice(shape_list)
color = random.choice(color_list)
clarity = random.choice(clarity_list)
cut = random.choice(cut_list)
carats = round(random.uniform(0.1, 14),2)
if carats < 0.3:
    price = random.randint(200, 600)
elif carats < 0.5:
    price = random.randint(600, 1000)
elif carats < 0.7:
    price = random.randint(1000, 1800)
elif carats < 1.5:
    price = random.randint(1800, 5000)
elif carats < 3:
    price = random.randint(5000, 17000)
elif carats < 5:
    price = random.randint(17000, 25000)
elif carats < 8:
    price = random.randint(30000, 300000)
elif carats <= 14:
    price = random.randint(300000, 1000000)
id = 'dmd_'+str(i)
name=str(carats)+' '+'ct'+' '+'Diamond'
sku = randomString()
new_id = %sql INSERT INTO inventory (name, price, sku) VALUES (:name, :price, :sku) RETURNING inventory_id
%sql INSERT INTO diamonds (shape, carats, color, clarity, cut, price, inventory_id) VALUES (:shape, :carats, :color, :clarity, :cut, :price, :new_id)
```

I need to get inventory_id after inserting values to the inventory table and then using that inventory_id insert values to the diamonds table.

I understand that I need to catch the inventory_id right after inserting values to inventory table. I am concerned about this part of code

```
new_id = %sql INSERT INTO inventory (name, price, sku) VALUES (:name, :price, :sku) RETURNING inventory_id
%sql INSERT INTO diamonds (shape, carats, color, clarity, cut, price, inventory_id) VALUES (:shape, :carats, :color, :clarity, :cut, :price, :new_id)
```

For that part, I got an error "(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'RowProxy'"

Are there other ways to assign inventory_id to a variable and use that to populate diamonds table?

Comment: I'm neither a postgres nor python guy,
But I think you can do both Inserts & returning of the id's in a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

@Srinika is correct. This could be done with Postgres stored procedures. But it can be taken a step further as it can be done is a single SQL statement, or a function consisting of just that single statement. That function would be:

```
create or replace function create_inventory_diamonds
                         ( name_in       varchar
                         , inv_price_in  integer
                         , sku_in        integer
                         , shape_in      varchar
                         , carats_in     real 
                         , color_in      varchar
                         , clarity_in    varchar 
                         , cut_in        varchar
                         , price_in      integer
                         )
  returns void
  language sql 
as $$ 
with inv as 
     ( insert into inventory(name, price, sku)
          values (name_in, inv_price_in, sku_in) 
        returning inventory_id
     )
insert into diamonds 
          ( shape
          , carats 
          , color 
          , clarity  
          , cut  
          , price 
          , inventory_id
          )
    select  shape_in
          , carats_in 
          , color_in  
          , clarity_in   
          , cut_in   
          , price_in  
          , inv.inventory_id  --reference back to CTE
     from inv;

$$;
```

What it does is create a common table expression (CTE, with clause) that inserts into inventory returning the generated inventory_id. The main portion the selects the other parameters along with the returned inventory_id and insert into diamonds. There is no return, indicated by "returns void" in function header.

Now my Python is pretty weak but I believe the single statement format would be valid. I think would result in something like although I absolutely unsure about the indentation, remember the entire thing is 1 statement.

```
 %sql  with inv as ( insert into inventory(name, price, sku) VALUES (:name, :price, :sku)   
       insert into diamonds ( shape, carats, color, clarity,cut, price, inventory_id)
       select  :shape, :carats, :color, :clarity, :cut, :price, inv.inventory_id;
```

There is a modeling change I would suggest: remove price from inventory.What should that column contain if I have more than 1 diamond. Or what happens one is delete one (or perhaps sold). That is a derivable value which can be calculated on as as needed basis.